# Unable to insert a row in Postgres database "ERROR: duplicate key value violates unique constraint" although there is no entry present in the table

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.3, postgresql-10

I have a table with schema :

```
    Table: "public.system_configuration_parameter"

        Column     |            Type             | Collation | Nullable |                     Default                      
    ---------------+-----------------------------+-----------+----------+--------------------------------------------------
     id            | integer                     |           | not null | nextval('system_configuration_id_seq'::regclass)
     name          | character varying           |           | not null | 
     type          | character varying           |           | not null | 
     value         | character varying           |           |          | 
     default_value | character varying           |           | not null | 
     date_added    | timestamp without time zone |           | not null | now()
     date_modified | timestamp without time zone |           | not null | now()

    Indexes:
        "system_configuration_parameter_pkey" PRIMARY KEY, btree (id)
        "system_configuration_parameter_name_key" UNIQUE CONSTRAINT, btree (name)
```

**The following query results into ERROR:**

```
insert into system_configuration_parameter (name, type, value ,default_value) values ('serverPerformanceMode','String','standardMode','standardMode');
ERROR:  duplicate key value violates unique constraint "system_configuration_parameter_name_key"
DETAIL:  Key (name)=(serverPerformanceMode) already exists.
```

The thing is there is no entry present in a table with name value as 'serverPerformanceMode'

```
shubhdb=# select value from system_configuration_parameter where name = ('serverPerformanceMode');
(0 rows)
```

I am using postgres 9.3, I have performed a migration of postgres to upgraded version 10. I currently have both the versions installed in my system.

I used to use the same database with the same structure and it used to work perfectly fine before. This even works fine with postgres-10 now, the problem occurs only when I use postgres-9.3 with the same build.

Does anyone have any idea about this? or has faced the same issue?

Thank you for reading.

Comment: I'm also facing the same issue in PostgreSQL 12

Answer (score 0):

This type of problem is usually caused by user error.  You are probably connecting to one database to do the insert, and a different one to do the query (or perhaps different schema's of the same database).  Can you make your code which does the insertion follow-up the error by running the query, using the same connection object, rather than running the query manually over a different connection?

Comment: Extending on @jjanes observation is the other common cause for this error: Duplicates in the _Input Data_. So that the error is effective self generating.

Comment: @Belayer True enough.  And the last likely cause is Row Level Security, but that didn't exist in 9.3.